# first bug on new theme :D

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

the gold, silver and bronze badges must change order!

[image]

Comment: They're in the right order (gold is normally listed first), it's that the bronze and gold icons are flipped (you have 3 gold badges and 25 bronze, but the display indicates 3 bronze and 25 gold)

Comment: @Mich I want said that too, you are right it just need to change gold and bronze icon.

Comment: what you don't like more gold badges? j/k. I had the css backwards on those, fixing now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have put in a fix, will be in the next deployment.